# Sonar Cloud Security Hotspot for Django manage.py file

Tags: django, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonar Analysis gives the following Security HotSpot in the manage.py file of my Django Project
"Make sure that command line arguments are used safely here"

On the following line

`execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` On the argv to be precise

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced this issue just today and after I have reviewed a lot of information about this and many posts I did something that worked for me:
First I have changed the import for sys at the begining of the file to import argparse instead.
To complete the changes I have changed the 'execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)' line for this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('parameters', metavar='N', type=str, nargs='+', help='parameters')
args = parser.parse_args()
command = args.parameters
command.insert(0,'manage.py')
execute_from_command_line(command)
```

This generate a parser and then get all the string arguments in args.parameters like an array and then I have added at the first option in the array the name of the file, which is 'manage.py'.
After that this worked for me.